# QWidget doesn't show when promoting to my own class in QT Designer

Tags: qt, qwidget, qt-designer

I'm trying to subclass QWidget to customize my own TitleBar (as i have made the main frame `FramelessWindowHint`).

And the subclass seems like:

```
TitleBar::TitleBar(QWidget *parent)
{
    this->setAutoFillBackground(true);

    int width = this->width();
    this->minButton = new QToolButton(this);
    this->closeButton = new QToolButton(this);
    this->icon = new QLabel(this);

    this->icon->setGeometry(0, 0, 25, 25);
    this->minButton->setGeometry(width - 46, 0, 23, 23);
    this->closeButton->setGeometry(width - 23, 0, 23, 23);

    QPixmap minPix = style()->standardPixmap(QStyle::SP_TitleBarMinButton);
    QPixmap closePix = style()->standardPixmap(QStyle::SP_TitleBarCloseButton);
    QPixmap iconPix = QPixmap(QString::fromUtf8(":/Resources/HandySearch.ico")).scaled(icon->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);

    this->icon->setPixmap(iconPix);
    this->minButton->setIcon(minPix);
    this->closeButton->setIcon(closePix);

    this->minButton->setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent;");
    this->closeButton->setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent;");
}
```

Then i turn to QT Designer and add a QWidget into the MainFrame , and promote it to my own class TitleBar, however , nothing seems to show up. But if i directly put the code(which creates minButton and closeButton) in the constructor of main frame, the buttons appear as expected .

So how could i do to customize my own title bar (or anything else) ? i don't know where i did wrong when subclassing QWidget and promote default widget to my own widget.

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Try to do it programmaticaly and then see differences in Qt Designer.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the generated code from `uic`.

Comment: Qt Designer doesn't show custom classes unless you have a Qt Designer plugin for those classes. Promote widgets in Qt Designer and do the remaining setup in the constructor. Promoted widgets should be shown up only in a running application.